# Torrent for the fastText pre-trained models?

Tags: nlp, language

I would like to download the pre-trained models for ~100 languages, which are ~3GB each.

(See https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md)

Is there a utility or .torrent somewhere for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A torrent would be more robust, but [here](https://gist.github.com/bittlingmayer/f6a58d1237525947d7b7f118f78139ed) is a workaround `download.sh` for now:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
    wget -c "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.${!i}.zip"
done
```

For example `./download.sh bg el ka hy ru fa es fr de it pt ar tr pl ko`

If stopped it will not re-start automatically, but if re-started it will continue from where it stopped.